# How can I move my codigniter databse to google cloud sql?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I want to move my codeigniter project database to google cloud sql but I didn't see phpmyadmin.

**How can i export my database to google and where do i get myconnection details, host,password,user and dbname just like I have on my local server?**

The documentation is not very clear to someone who is not familiar with that environment. Thanks

**This is my database config file**

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '104.197.147.157',

    'username' => 'mylasttestingaccount',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'mydatabase',

    /*
    'username' => 'develope_prakash',
    'password' => '[REDACTED]',
    'database' => 'develope_ubah',
    */
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a multipart question, so I'll answer the questions as I understand them.

**NOTE:** Cloud SQL instances are not managed using phpmyadmin, but they are managed mainly using the Cloud Console. This also means that whatever changes you want to make (such as adding users) needs to be done using the Cloud Console, or from one of the other management tools such as the [gcloud command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/).

1) You'll need to [create](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance) an instance first. I highly advise a 2nd gen instance.

2) Adding a user can be done from the Console or the gcloud command line tool. Both are described in the same [article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users).

3) As for importing data from another database, there's a [separate article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing) on this. There's some conditions that need to be met before you can successfully import data. The export needs to be created in a certain way. This is described in detail in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/creating-sqldump-csv). After getting the export you can import it using the steps described in [the first article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing) I linked in this paragraph.

To wrap it up, I highly advise you to read through the documentation about Cloud SQL. Any of the ones I linked have a list of articles on the left side which contains just about everything you need to know about Cloud SQL.

One additional note, **NEVER** provide passwords for anything on a public site like SO.